# How to add more columns to order records in grid in KENDO

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

The question might be very simple but I have not found examples or documentation how to do order by multiple columns for KENDO grid. The part in the `cshtml` file is like this:

.ClientDetailTemplateId("addresses")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Cid))
        .Read(read => read.Action("SelectAddr", "Addr").Data("get_addr_grid_params"))
        .PageSize(20)
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(m => m.zipcode))
    )

How can I add one more column to order by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
.Sort(x =>
{
x.Add(y=>y.DownloadDate).Descending());
x.Add(y=>y.DueDate).Descending());
}
```